# FQL returns empty array when query checkin table

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

I am using the following FQL query to query user's checkins with iOS Facebook SDK 3.5.1, but always got two empty array in the response:

```
{"placeQuery":"SELECT name,page_id from place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT target_id FROM #checkinQuery)","checkinQuery":"SELECT checkin_id,coords,tagged_uids,target_id,message,timestamp FROM checkin WHERE author_uid=me()"}
```

But if I paste the same queries in the Facebook API explorer, I can get the results with the same permissions I requested in the app. And I used to get it work with same code. When I made the migration for Facebook's recommendations (The July 2013 Breaking Changes: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) and upgrade SDK to 3.5.1, it no long works.

Any suggestion how do I deal with this issue? Is it a bug in Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a bug from Facebook. After I added "user_checkins" permission, problem was solved. But according to Facebook document, "user_checkins" was already superseded by "user_status" on March 2012. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/ .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I've tried several things:

1. See if the FQL worked on [FQL Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Add permissions on the iOS side such as 'user_photos' for albums

But what really solved the issue for me was that my simulator was not asking me for permissions on those.

> So, I manually went on [FQL Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and clicked on 'Graph API Explorer' next to Applications and then clicked 'myApplicationName' then selected the permissions manually.

I hope this helps.